# how to drop other results in spark streaming?

Tags: conditional-statements, spark-streaming, word-count

I wanted to make the word count streaming with only showing which word I would like to see with Twitter.

So, I made the cords as like below

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization
import twitter4j.Status
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization

val appName = "TwitterData"

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
val hashTags = "XRP"
val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder
val prop = new Properties()

cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("key number").setOAuthConsumerSecret("key number").setOAuthAccessToken("key number").setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("key number")

val bld = cb.build()
val tf = new TwitterFactory(bld)
val twitter = tf.getInstance()
val filters = Array(hashTags).toSeq
val auth = new OAuthAuthorization(bld)
val twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(auth), filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

twitterStream.cache()

val lines = twitterStream.map(status => status.getText)
lines.print()

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(x => {
  if (x == "xrp" || x == "ripple"){
    (x, 1)
  } else {
  }
})

pairs.print()

ssc.start()
```

It works fine with Spark Streaming with Twitter, but as follow the result, I want to drop all the empty blanks except for the result which I wanted to get.

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1603866040000 ms
-------------------------------------------
@RuleXRP I need 15to25 usd per xrp
RT @Grayscale: 10/27/20 UPDATE: Net Assets Under Management, Holdings per Share, and Market Price per Share for our Investment Products.

T....

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1603866040000 ms
-------------------------------------------
()
()
()
()
()
()
(xrp,1)
()
()
()
...
```

How can I do that? And if is there any ways to take the only results what I want to get better then my cords, please let me know. I need your help.
I deeply appreciative for your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val pairs = words.map(x => {
  if (x == "xrp" || x == "ripple"){
    (x, 1)
  } else {
  }
})
```

this maps your result

instead you could use a filter before mapping it which would reduce your code a little bit:

```
val pairs = words
  .filter(x => x == "xrp" || x == "ripple")
  .map(x => (x, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But if I run with your code.. I can't even see the result that how many times the words are mentioned...

Comment: Didnt you try printing? There shouldn't be much of a difference between our solutions I just filter unwanted stuff out

Comment: I tried printing but, as you can see, I got only the result with empty brackets. And I tried use the map first then filter. I guess I didn't tried to use filter first and then map.

Comment: how did you try to use filter first? There is no point mapping stuff you will filter out anyway also if you used it with the exact semantic the filter would not work anymore because you are filtering on a tuple. Did you rewrite it?

Comment: I'm a just beginner and try to learn with top - down method. So, it could possible I had no basic knowledge that much.. Through this solution I could learn how to use map and filter more specifically. Thanks